# Using np.where returns error after using .any()

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, where-clause

I'm working on a dataframe that needs to create a large amount of flags, depending on multiple conditions. I'm using `np.where` but now I'm running into this error

```
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

For replicability and simplicity, I'm only sharing the part of the code that produces the error together with the columns that are used.
Dataframe being used:

```
     Data  Uniques  day_a1  day_a2  day_a3
0       1        1       3     NaN     NaN
1       2        2      14    15.0     NaN
2       2        1      10    10.0     NaN
3       3        1      10    10.0    10.0
802     2        2      12     NaN    29.0
806     1        1      29     NaN     NaN
```

Code that generates the error:

```
df['flag_3.3.3.1.1'] = np.where(
    (
        (df['Data'] == 3) & 
        (df['day_a1'] != 10) & 
        (df['Uniques'] == 3) & #I ran this separately and it was fine
        (df['day_a1'] > 27 or df['day_a1'] < 4).any()),'flag',np.nan)
```

I seem to still have issues after passying `.any()` after the `or`.

Comment: http://idownvotedbecau.se/nodebugging/ Split your long, long statement into parts; if necessary, multiple statements. And see what each part produces.

Comment: That's a *really* complicated set of operations you have there *inside* your function call. Have you considered splitting it into multiple statements as preparation? Would help us readers and yourself to get a (much) better idea of what's actually going on

Comment: Who is the magician that solved this? Thanks a lot! I wasn't sure to how to split them without breaking the code (I honestly tried).

Comment: `a= (df['Data'] == 3)`; `b=(df['day_a1'] != 10)`; etc; `x=a & b & c <etc>`; `np.where(x, '3.3.3.1.1', nan)`.

Comment: Editing to capture the error!

Comment: @CeliusStingher You're welcome :) If line-breaking code manually is too tricky, maybe look into running [`black`](https://black.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) on your code. Although writing code such that lines don't end up longer than 80-100 characters to begin with is usually a good start too

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try replacing

```
(df['day_a1'] > 27 or df['day_a1'] < 4)
```

by

```
((df['day_a1'] > 27) | (df['day_a1'] < 4))
```

Note the use of `|` and the additional parenthesis for the precedence.

Comment: Yes, this makes it work! I did not know about the use of | Thanks a lot.

Comment: @CeliusStingher See the following question and its answers: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36921951/truth-value-of-a-series-is-ambiguous-use-a-empty-a-bool-a-item-a-any-o